# One backend Restful API design consideration

Tags: api, rest, server

I have q question in designing back-end server. 
I design a restful API for feeding data for mobile app clients. Clients may be more than 10000 and the data change rate is not that high. So, I would like to have a List (collection) to store the whole data for feeding clients in web server and design a scheduler to update this list by accessing database only every 1 hour. In this way, the server don't need to access database every time the client send a request to the server. I think it is more efficient.
I have some questions:
1. Is this a good way to prevent accessing database too frequently?
2. When the client send a request and the list is updating from database, what would happen? the client get the old data or an error (exception) would happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of caching the entire database once every hour, you could simply cache individual records or queries. This way you don't have to store the entire data-set in memory, which could prove to be expensive.
2. It depends on how you implement the cache, but your client would probably receive stale data.

Comment: Also, receive stale data is ok in my application, as long as it is not error or exception. Also, in my condition, yes, I only cache part of one table instead of the entire database for those 10000 clients, because those clients send requests in a fixed rate, say every 20 minutes. But only part of client need to get data, depends on whether their data was changed internally or not. So, I only cache updated data, Is it a good idea? I check some cache mechanism, like Spring Cache, that doesn't  fit in my case.

Comment: I may have a simple solution for this. Maybe, just create a new instance for this List each time when updating and then replace with the old one. In this way, at most, client get stale data, but definitely no error or exceptions would happen. How do you think?